# How can I create a dropdown sidebar in WordPress

Tags: wordpress, button, sidebar

I'm trying to have a button in my navbar that will make my sidebar come out when it's clicked.
I've already created the sidebar and its functional, but I want to link the sidebar to a button that is in the navigation menu.

Answer (score 0):

You can Toggle the sidebar element on the navbar button click

For example, this is your navbar

```
<nav>
<button id="main"> Side</button>
</nav>
```

And this is your Sidebar

```
<div id="sidebar" style="display:none;">
</div>
```

The JS code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#main").click(function () {
        $("#sidebar").toggle();
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: How do I add this in WordPress?

Comment: Add this ID "main" on your navigation button and add this ID " sidebar" on your sidebar and place the script in your footer.php file.